# xoxco tagging : apply to newly added DOM elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the [xoxco tagging plugin](https://github.com/xoxco/jQuery-Tags-Input).
In my $(document).ready I'm calling the following to make all of them taggable :

```
$('.tagsForFoo').tagsInput({
});
```

Later in the code, elements are being dynamically created.
How do I apply it to these **newly created DOM** objects ?

Comment: How are you creating, and adding, these new nodes?

Comment: $('.foosParent').prepend(newlyCreatedDIV);